# Adding waypoint in ns3 for waypoint mobility model

Tags: c++, simulation, ns2, ns-3

I was trying adding waypoints for waypoint mobility model but i am not able to do so. This is what I did

```
Ptr<WaypointMobilityModel> waypoints = CreateObject<WaypointMobilityModel> (); 
waypoints->AddWaypoint (Waypoint (Seconds (2.0),Vector (25.0, 0, 0))); 
waypoints->AddWaypoint (Waypoint (Seconds (5.0),Vector (50.0, 0, 0))); 
mobility.SetMobilityModel(waypoints);  //mobility is my MobilityHelper
```

SetMobilityModel expects a string but is instead getting a ptr when is called with parameter waypoints. Could you tell what should be the correct way for doing so?

This is the error i got:

```
no matching function for call to ‘ns3::MobilityHelper::SetMobilityModel(ns3::Ptr<ns3::WaypointMobilityModel>&)’
 mobility.SetMobilityModel(waypoints);
 note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘ns3::Ptr<ns3::WaypointMobilityModel>’ to ‘std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}’
```

Comment: The one and only ns3 Forum is https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

Answer (score 0):

---

The one and only ns3 Forum is  https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/ns-3-users

---